# my mic in Headset don't work after last update window 11

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headset

I have a problem with my mic in my headset don't work after last update.
it was have to option stereo and hands free AG work when select hands free AG with Mono audio in windows 10. and 11 work auto but now it not work and don't find option hands free AG

my mic in headset wireless don't work after last update window 11

Comment: Check if Windows 11 has changed the driver for your device.

Comment: I don't see any changes to the driver